# How to control speed of a Servo motor using arduino Mega

Tags: arduino

I am working on a project in which I need to change the speed of servo motors. The hardware I am using is an Arduino Mega 2560 board and I am using Servo.h library to control servos. Servo rotates from o to 180 degree. I am using 12 servo motors in the project and have to control them simultaneously. Is there a way?

Answer (score 1):

You can use `delay()` function in a while or for loop

Example:

```
Servo s;
s.attach(9);
for(int i=0 ; i<180 ; i++)
{
    s.write(i);
    delay(10); //10 milisecond
}
```

Comment: i have to control 12 servo motors simultaneously, loop will disallow me to do that...

Answer (score 0):

**If they all are the same degree, try this code below.**

**At the very top** (Not between any "{}"s)**:**

```
#include <Servo.h> 
Servo S1;
Servo S2;
Servo S3;
Servo S4;
Servo S5;
Servo S6;
Servo S7;
Servo S8;
Servo S9;
Servo S10;
Servo S11;
Servo S12;
```

**Put this in** `Setup`**:**

```
S1.attach(1);
S2.attach(2);
S3.attach(3);
S4.attach(4);
S5.attach(5);
S6.attach(6);
S7.attach(7);
S8.attach(8);
S9.attach(9);
S10.attach(10);
S11.attach(11);
S12.attach(12);
```

You need to change the pin numbers.

**Just put this anywhere** (Not between any "{}"s)**:**

```
void TurnServos(int toDegree){
  servosAt = S1.read;
  if(servosAt == toDegree){

  }
  if(servosAt > toDegree){
    while(S1.read > toDegree){
      int currentToDegree = S1.read - 1;
      S1.write(currentToDegree);
      S2.write(currentToDegree);
      S3.write(currentToDegree);
      S4.write(currentToDegree);
      S5.write(currentToDegree);
      S6.write(currentToDegree);
      S7.write(currentToDegree);
      S8.write(currentToDegree);
      S9.write(currentToDegree);
      S10.write(currentToDegree);
      S11.write(currentToDegree);
      S12.write(currentToDegree);
      delay(10);         //Adjust this to make it faster or slower.
    }
  }
  if(servosAt < toDegree){
    while(S1.read < toDegree){
      int currentToDegree = S1.read + 1;
      S1.write(currentToDegree);
      S2.write(currentToDegree);
      S3.write(currentToDegree);
      S4.write(currentToDegree);
      S5.write(currentToDegree);
      S6.write(currentToDegree);
      S7.write(currentToDegree);
      S8.write(currentToDegree);
      S9.write(currentToDegree);
      S10.write(currentToDegree);
      S11.write(currentToDegree);
      S12.write(currentToDegree);
      delay(10);         //Adjust this to make it faster or slower.
    }
  }
}
void ClearServos(){
  int startDegree = 90;   //Change this number to anything you want.
  S1.write(startDegree);
  S2.write(startDegree);
  S3.write(startDegree);
  S4.write(startDegree);
  S5.write(startDegree);
  S6.write(startDegree);
  S7.write(startDegree);
  S8.write(startDegree);
  S9.write(startDegree);
  S10.write(startDegree);
  S11.write(startDegree);
  S12.write(startDegree);
}
```

---

**How to use this:**
In `setup` **before you do anything with servos but after the part I told you to put in setup**, use **`ClearServos();`** to prepare the servos to be used. (This probably isn't necessarily, but I don't know what happens when you use `S1.read` without changing it and if the servos are at different positions, it will fix problems. It can be avoided if it won't cause problems, but I think you should use it if you can.) All of them will turn to 90 degrees. (90 degrees can be changed with the variable `startDegree` in `void ClearServos`.)

To turn them, use **`TurnServos(90);`**. 90 is the degree you want it to turn to.

---

Haven't tested this because I don't have a Mega or 12 servos. Please comment if you notice any errors since this is huge. I spent a lot of time on this so I hope I helped. :)

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can put some resistors in series to your servo's VCC pin, before your servo motor to decrease the voltage across; thus slowing it. However, this will cause your servo's to be "constant" speed.

An alternative could be to put a transistor in between your servo VCC connection and set PWM on base pin to regulate current (to regulate speed), but that would cost you an extra pin per servo if you're not using a multiplexer in between; and could make your design a little more complicated.

Answer (score 0):

delayMicroseconds(value) closest to 90-null is slowest for 360 servos both pan and carriage on my timelapse rig, shoot move shoot, in time with the mechanical shutter clicker (mini standard servo).

Answer (score -1):

in Servo library WriteMicroseconds(...) function sets servo speed.

for more information please [click](http://arduino.cc/en/Reference/ServoWriteMicroseconds)

Comment: I am using a standard servo, 'servo.writeMicroseconds()' will change the position of the shaft, not the speed!